# How do I remove the keys from Local machine\SOFTWARE?

Tags: c#, windows, registry, uac

I tried to delete a test key through a C# script. The following code is my script, I also added admin value in manifest file for this project UAC. But it still doesn't work. Even restarted Visual Studio 2017 with Admin mode.
The error message said Cannot write to the registry key.
Not sure what's wrong in the script.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;


namespace temp_code_tester
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Get current login account info from another Class
        //string userName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        //var SecCheck = new SecutriyProcesser();
        //SecCheck.AddRule(userName);


        var RunCheck = new AccessRegistry();
        RunCheck.ACL("Test");

    }
}

class AccessRegistry
{
    public void ACL(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Getting the registry keys.....");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------\n");

        //Open the SOFTWARE keys and input those keys into array
        RegistryKey SoftKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE");
        string[] lists = SoftKey.GetSubKeyNames();

        foreach (string KeyName in lists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(KeyName);
        }

        foreach (string value in lists)
        {
            if (value.Contains(name)) // if we find the key, then lists all subkeys
            {
                //Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKeyTree(value);
                Console.WriteLine("\nMatch one: {0}", value);

                var RightKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\" + value);
                string[] SubList = RightKey.GetSubKeyNames();

                foreach (string SubValue in SubList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Folder: {0} is under this key", SubValue);
                }

                if (SubList.Length > 1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SoftKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(value);
                        Console.WriteLine("\nThe folder {0} has been removed", value);
                    }
                    catch (Exception er)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", er.Message);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SoftKey.DeleteSubKey(value);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        SoftKey.Close();
    }
}

class SecutriyProcesser
{
    // A method about add enough roles for current window account
    public void AddRule(string userName)
    {
        RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
        rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(userName,
            RegistryRights.FullControl,
            InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
            PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
            AccessControlType.Allow));
    }

    // Try to list the security level
    public void ShowSecurity(RegistrySecurity security)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nCurrent access rules:\r\n");

        foreach (RegistryAccessRule ar in security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount)))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("        User: {0}", ar.IdentityReference);
            Console.WriteLine("        Type: {0}", ar.AccessControlType);
            Console.WriteLine("      Rights: {0}", ar.RegistryRights);
            Console.WriteLine(" Inheritance: {0}", ar.InheritanceFlags);
            Console.WriteLine(" Propagation: {0}", ar.PropagationFlags);
            Console.WriteLine("   Inherited? {0}", ar.IsInherited);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the 'writable' parameter of the 'OpenSubkey' method.
Try this :

```
RegistryKey SoftKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE", true);
```

It should work like this.

**EDIT :** This method will probably fail if you don't run Visual Studio as Administrator while debugging.